# There is any difference between the static property and static function in Swift

Tags: swift, static

I want to know if there is any difference between any of these 2 declarations?

```
static var sessionConfiguration: URLSessionConfiguration = {
    let myConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let base64LoginString = EndpointController.getBase64StringLoginWithUserAndPasswordV2()
    myConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : base64LoginString]
    return myConfig
}()
    
static func getURLSessionConfigurationDefault() -> URLSessionConfiguration {
    let myConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let base64LoginString = EndpointController.getBase64StringLoginWithUserAndPasswordV2()
    myConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : base64LoginString]
    return myConfig
}
```

Comment: One will return the same instance on every access, the other one a new instance for each access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `var t = { }()` syntax: the `{ }` is a function that returns a value, and the `()` is calling that function ***once*** to set the initial value of the variable `t`. You can change `t` to something else later, because it's a `var`.  That syntax is like `var a = 42` but instead of 42 you set it to the result of running a function, like: `{ return 42 }()` but that function isn't run every time you read (or write) the value `t`

The `getURLSessionConfigurationDefault() -> URLSessionConfiguration` is always creating a new instance of something and returning that new instance  - the result of the function.